# Legend not showing in D3Plus Scatter Plot

Tags: javascript, d3plus

I'm trying to use D3Plus to build a scatter plot to show compliance numbers, and would like to have a legend for the different points- but when I add the legend function to my graph, nothing shows up on the page.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- load D3js -->
<script src="/lib/d3/d3.js"></script>

<!-- load D3plus after D3js -->
<script src="/lib/d3plus/d3plus.js"></script>

<!-- create container element for visualization -->
<div id="viz" style = "height: 90vh; width: 99vw;"></div>

<script>
  // sample data array
  var sample_data = [
    //Quad I
    {"% In Compliance": 100, "% In App": 100, "name": "1"},
    //Quad II
    {"% In Compliance": -3, "% In App": 100, "name": "2"},
    {"% In Compliance": -26, "% In App": 100, "name": "3"},
    {"% In Compliance": -55, "% In App": 100, "name": "4"},
    {"% In Compliance": -76, "% In App": 100, "name": "5"},
    //Quad III
    {"% In Compliance": -36, "% In App": -25, "name": "6"},
    {"% In Compliance": -66, "% In App": -4, "name": "7"},
    //Quad IV
    {"% In Compliance": 96, "% In App": -1, "name": "8"},
    {"% In Compliance": 87, "% In App": -1, "name": "9"},
    {"% In Compliance": 72, "% In App": -5, "name": "10"},
    {"% In Compliance": 55, "% In App": -6, "name": "11"},
    {"% In Compliance": 52, "% In App": -5, "name": "12"},
    {"% In Compliance": 45, "% In App": -5, "name": "13"},
    {"% In Compliance": 38, "% In App": -1, "name": "14"},
    {"% In Compliance": 29, "% In App": -2, "name": "15"},
    {"% In Compliance": 19, "% In App": -7, "name": "16"},
    {"% In Compliance": 9, "% In App": -7, "name": "17"}
  ]


  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .data(sample_data)  // data to use with the visualization
    .type("scatter")    // visualization type
    .id("name")         // key for which our data is unique on
    .x({value:"% In Compliance", range:[-104,104]})         // key for x-axis
    .y({value:"% In App", range:[-104,106]})        // key for y-axis
    .axes({"ticks": false})
    .format({ "text" : function( text , key ) {
        return text;
        } 
    })
    .legend({"size": 50})
    .size(25)
    .draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the legend to appear, you have to explicitly set the color method. By default, shapes are colored based on their ID, so in you case all you would need to do is add this line:

```
.color("name")
```